# How to discretize in space with periodic boundary conditions

Tags: discrete-mathematics

How to discretize this equation in space
$$u''-ku'-m u=0$$
with BCs $u(\pm c)=u(0)$ ? I tried to discretize in space like so:
$$x_j=jh$$
$$u''=\frac{u_{j+1}-2u_j+u_{j-1}}{h^2}$$
$$u'=\frac{u_{j+1}-u_{j-1}}{2h}$$

Therefore, I got
$$\frac{u_{j+1}-2u_j+u_{j-1}}{h^2}-k \frac{u_{j+1}-u_{j-1}}{2h} - m u_j=0$$

I don't know if this is correct or not, and what the next step is to write this as a matrix equation. Also, how can I write the BCs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without periodic boundary conditions, the domain of your solution is $[-c,c]$ (where $c \ge 0$). If $h$ is your step size, then you want to have an integer number of steps between $x = -c$ and $x = c$ but such that $x=0$ is one of the points in the grid. So, with
$$
x_j = a + b\,j
$$
you want to have
$$
\begin{align}
x_0   &= 0 &\implies a  &= 0 \\
x_{N} &= c &\implies bN &= c
\end{align}
$$

Thus, $x_j = (c/N)\,j$. But you also want $x_{j+1} - x_j = h$, so $c/N = h$ and, hence,
$$
x_j = h\,j
\quad\mbox{with}\quad h = \frac{c}{N} \quad\mbox{and}\quad N \in \mathbb{N}-\{0\}
$$

To cover the entire domain, however, you need $j \in \mathbb{Z}$, $|\,j\,| \le N$. The rest of your derivation is correct.

But you want periodic boundary conditions, so:
$$
u_j = u_{j \pm N}
\qquad\mbox{for}\qquad
j = 0, \pm N, \pm 2N, \pm 3N\ldots
$$
or, more simply,
$$
u_0 = u_{kN}
\qquad\mbox{for}\qquad
k \in \mathbb{Z}
$$
and now $j \in \mathbb{Z}$ without any restrictions.

To write your discretised equation as a matrix equation, just re-arrange it, collecting terms with identical indices together. You'll then see pretty easily how to write the resulting equation as a matrix equation.

Note that the parameters you need are $N$, $c$, and $m$. All the rest is computable from the above.

Comment: Wouldn't the usual statement of periodic boundary conditions be that $u_0 = u_{kN}$ for $k \in \mathbb{Z}$, not $u_{kN} = 0$?

Comment: Yes, I misread the question. I read 0 rather than $(0)$.

Comment: @gleedadswell Thank you for pointing that out. +1

Comment: @wltrup Many thanks for your help.